# Order Created Date is displaying today date

Tags: magento-1.9

I am displaying **Cusomters** , **Customer's Orders** , **Order Created Date** in excel sheet.

**Issue** :

If there is **no order** created by customer, than Order created date is displaying today date, but i dont want to display that, means that field should be blank....

**Example** :

[image]

In above image in 3rd row , Customer [Nawab] Created order, so its displaying correct order date. but in 2nd row , customer did not created order, so its displaying today's date, but it should be **blank**....

```
<?php

$newordercollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerArray['entity_id']);   
$collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
$firstItem = $newordercollection->getFirstItem();
$orderID = $firstItem->getIncrementId();

$data = $newordercollection->getData();
$createdAt = $firstItem->getCreatedAt();

$myTimezone = new \DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
$UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC"); 
$newDate = new \DateTime( $createdAt, $UTC ); 
$newDate->setTimezone( $myTimezone ); 
$createdAt = $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$customerREquiredArray['order date']= $createdAt;
```

Full code : https://pastebin.com/2bHGSZiw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}
// Only for urls // Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
try {
    Mage::getConfig()->init();
    Mage::app();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
}
ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
$customerCount = 0;
try {
    //configure the collection filters.
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email');

    //Add a page size to the result set.
    $collection->setPageSize(50);
    //discover how many page the result will be.
    $pages = $collection->getLastPageNumber();
    $currentPage = 1;
    //This is the file to append the output to.
    $fp = fopen('customers.csv', 'w');
    $addedKeys = false;
    do {
        //Tell the collection which page to load.
        $collection->setCurPage($currentPage);
        $collection->load();
        foreach ($collection as $customer) {
            $customerArray = $customer->toArray();

            $newordercollection = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customerArray['entity_id']);
            $collection->setOrder('entity_id', 'ASC');
            $firstItem = $newordercollection->getFirstItem();
            $orderID = $firstItem->getIncrementId();

// date
            $data = $newordercollection->getData();

            $createdAt = $firstItem->getCreatedAt();
            if ($createdAt != '') {
                $myTimezone = new \DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
                $UTC = new DateTimeZone("UTC");
                $newDate = new \DateTime($createdAt, $UTC);
                $newDate->setTimezone($myTimezone);
                $createdAt = $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            }


// get product information

            foreach ($newordercollection as $orderkey => $ordervalue) {
                foreach ($ordervalue->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                    $sku = $item->getSku();
                }
                $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId();
                $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
            }
            //write the collection array as a CSV.

            $customerREquiredArray['customer ID'] = $customerArray['entity_id'];
            $customerREquiredArray['First name'] = $customerArray['firstname'];
            $customerREquiredArray['Email'] = $customerArray['email'];
            $customerREquiredArray['order id'] = $orderID;
            $customerREquiredArray['order date'] = $createdAt;
            $customerREquiredArray['products'] = $sku;

            if ($addedKeys == false) {
                $keys = array_keys($customerREquiredArray);
                fputcsv($fp, $keys);
                $addedKeys = true;
            }
            //var_dump($customerArray); echo "\n\n";
            fputcsv($fp, $customerREquiredArray);
            //fwrite($fp,print_r($customerArray,true) . chr(10) );
            $customerCount++;
        }
        $currentPage++;
        //make the collection unload the data in memory so it will pick up the next page when load() is called.
        $collection->clear();
        //break; //DEBUG
        echo "Finished page $currentPage of $pages \n";
    } while ($currentPage <= $pages);
    fclose($fp);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //$response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    Mage::printException($e);
}
echo "Saved $customerCount customers to csv file \n";
```